# Create new dataframe (column1 x column1) based on the counting column1 from old dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, data-cleaning

Here is what I currently have:

```
print(df)

   id  event_id  people_id
0   1   45430.0         30
1   2   45430.0        130
2   3   45430.0         96
3   4   45430.0         77
4   5   45431.0        130
5   6   45432.0         92
6   7   45433.0         77
```

How can i transform this to df1 so that we are counting the number of different events each people_id has with eachother?  The output of df1 should look like this:

```
print(df1)

   30  77  96  130
30   1  1   1   1
77   1  2   1   2
96   1  1   1   1
130  1  2   1   2
```

Comment: Would you mind adding your current attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try:

```
(df.merge(df, on='event_id')
   .groupby(['people_id_x', 'people_id_y'])
   .size()
   .unstack('people_id_x', fill_value=0)
)
```

Output:

```
people_id_x  30   77   92   96   130
people_id_y                         
30             1    1    0    1    1
77             1    2    0    1    1
92             0    0    1    0    0
96             1    1    0    1    1
130            1    1    0    1    2
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with `dot` after `crosstab`

```
s = pd.crosstab(df.event_id, df.people_id)
out = s.T.dot(s)
out
Out[59]: 
people_id  30   77   92   96   130
people_id                         
30           1    1    0    1    1
77           1    2    0    1    1
92           0    0    1    0    0
96           1    1    0    1    1
130          1    1    0    1    2
```